# Android:SlidingMenu(jfeinstein) does it really toggle?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I have made an Activity with two fragments.Fragment A acts as a menu,while the other works  as  a  content. I just designed the UI like this:Fragment B with a listview is always shown in your vision. When you click an Item in the listview, the left slidingmenu shall be drawn to the right and fragment B with a menu is shown and it shall be closed when I pull the margin of the fragment A. **After sth finished in fragment A ,fragment B shall update its listview data.Fragment B shall show its changes when fragment A  is invisible(Slidingmenu is showing and shall be closed)**
  As the guide tells ,I call the toggle method in the listview item clicklistener and insert necessary Log messages in it. My problem is like as below.

------------Fragment B (ListView)-----------------

```
OnItemClickListener listViewItemClickListener=new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int  position, long id) {           
        mCurCheckPosition=position;
        ListView lv=(ListView)parent;
        Cursor cr=(Cursor)lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
        mcons_no=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("cons_no"));
        Log.i(TAG, "cons_no:"+mcons_no+"is selected!");
        fragmentActivity.startManagingCursor(cr);
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("cons_no", mcons_no);
        bundle.putString("task_no", mtask_no);
        Fragment mLeftMenu=LeftMenuFragment.newInstance(bundle);
        fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                replace(R.id.frame_menu, mLeftMenu).commit();
        SlidingMenu slidingMenu=fragmentActivity.getSlidingMenu();
        Log.i("isMenuShowing", String.valueOf(slidingMenu.isMenuShowing()));
        /*if(slidingMenu.isMenuShowing()){**//it is never implemented but the slidingmenu can showcontent**

            Log.i("showContent", "showContent");
            slidingMenu.showContent();
            new RefreshListView().execute("task_no=?",orderBy[sequenceFlag]);//update the listview
        }else{**// it is always implemented when slidingmenu is not shown.
            slidingMenu.showMenu();**
            Log.i("showMenu", "showMenu");
        }
        */
        fragmentActivity.toggle();
        //new RefreshListView().execute("task_no=?",orderBy[sequenceFlag]);

    }   
};
```

The key problem is I have not informed of the slidingmenu sliding principle. I just hope to know when the slidingmenu is to closed then I can make changes. Appreciate your answers,Thank you for attention!

Comment: to toggle a slidingmenu, use getSlidingMenu().toggle(); inside an if condition, if(getSlidingMenu().isShowing() or isMenuShowing() [not sure] ..

Comment: Thank you for your time. How can I accurately find the place to close the slidingmenu so I can call the update listview method?

Comment: if you could please explain your needs then i could guide where exactly to close the slidingmenu.

Comment: does fragmentActivity.toggle() close the menu ?? i mean is that what it has to do? then replace that line with getslidingmenu().toggle(), inside the if condition getslidingmenu.ismenushowing()

Comment: Yes ,it really does. I hope before it closed, it shall send message to another fragment to update its UI. As a result, I need to accurately find the place to close the slidingmenu before which I can call updatelistview method.

Comment: Sth strange is that toggle() equals to if(slidingmenu.ismenushowing()){ slidingmenu.showcontent;}

Comment: Sth strange is that toggle() equals to if(slidingmenu.ismenushowing()){ slidingmenu.showcontent();}else{ slidingmenu.showmenu();} I have tested it that showmenu can be implemented but showcontent cannot. Instead, slidingmenu can be closed with a log message(CustomViewBehind:behind INVISIBLE) and ismenushowing is false never true before.

Comment: have you tried instantiating a sliding menu using slidingmenu = new SlidingMenu(this) ??

Comment: and inorder to show the menu, u could use getSlidingMenu.toggle(), that will set the isMenuShowing to true

Comment: I just used slidingmenu=getSlidingmenu(); I will try your suggestion.Thanks.